# Create content-editable div following span with text inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a image of what kind of effect I'm trying to have:

```
      ICON   LINE - 1 Some text Inside a div element
             and the next line should start
             here

      ICON   LINE - 2 Some text Inside a div element
             and the next line should start
             here

      ICON   LINE - 3 Some text Inside a div element
             and the next line should start
             here
```

And here is the code I tried:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span style="padding-left: 40px;">ICON</span>
        <div contenteditable="true" style="display:inline-block; padding-left: 20px; width:200; position: absolute;">
              <font> LINE 1 -- Some text Inside a div element and the next line should start here kjdaskjdaskldjaskldjaskldjaskldjaskljdaskljdaslkjdkl</font>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div>
        <span style="padding-left: 40px;">ICON</span>
        <div contenteditable="true" style="display:inline-block; padding-left: 20px; width:200; position: absolute;">
              <font>LINE 2 -- Some text Inside a div element and the next line should start here kjdaskjdaskldjaskldjaskldjaskldjaskljdaskljdaslkjdkl</font>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/supersuraccoon/djv83qpd/1/

It's almost there but as you can see in the link above all the text are overlapping.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You need a scroll or you need to extend the space between the div?

Comment: Why do you need absolute positioning?

Comment: Currently the content inside the two div (containing line1, line2) are overlapped.  I want the second div two follow the first one (say there is a 20px in between them). You can check the jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget `absolute` positioning. Add `px` to your `width`s and add `vertical-align:top;` to your divs so

```
 <div contenteditable="true" style="display:inline-block; padding-left: 20px; width:200px; vertical-align:top;">
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/djv83qpd/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :: [i have added only `<br> <br>`]

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span style="padding-left: 40px;">ICON</span>
        <div contenteditable="true" style="display:inline-block; padding-left: 20px; width:200; position: absolute;">
              <font> LINE 1 -- Some text Inside a div element and the next line should start here kjdaskjdaskldjaskldjaskldjaskldjaskljdaskljdaslkjdkl</font>
        </div>    
    </div>
<br><br>
    <div>
        <span style="padding-left: 40px;">ICON</span>
        <div contenteditable="true" style="display:inline-block; padding-left: 20px; width:200; position: absolute;">
              <font>LINE 2 -- Some text Inside a div element and the next line should start here kjdaskjdaskldjaskldjaskldjaskldjaskljdaskljdaslkjdkl</font>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

fiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/djv83qpd/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="blocks clearfix">
                <div class="image">
                    Image1
                </div>
                <div class="lines">
                    <div>Line one text</div>
                    <div>First block text First block text First block text</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="blocks clearfix">
                <div class="image">
                    Image2
                </div>
                <div  class="lines">
                    <div>Line two text</div>
                    <div>Second block text Second block text Second block text</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="blocks clearfix">
                <div class="image">
                    Image3
                </div>
                <div class="lines">
                    <div>Line three text</div>
                    <div>Third block text Third block text Third block text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css is

```
.clearfix:after {
           content: " ";
           visibility: hidden;
           display: block;
           height: 0;
           clear: both;
        }
        .container{         
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 70%;
        }
        .blocks .image, .blocks .lines{ 
            float: left;
        }
        .blocks .image {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            margin: 5px;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
```

[Fiddle is](https://jsfiddle.net/SolaceInfotech/5ds2fp5L/)